# No endpoint on cosume webservice application

Tags: c#, visual-studio, wcf

I am learning to create a WCF service. I tested my service that is worked when I tested it using SoapUi. Now I am creating a testing website to add this service as service reference. When I call the method of the service, I got the error "Could not find default endpoint element that references contract". I searched the web and still no idea to fix it. Would someone help me what I should do or show me the example code. Thanks.

There is my service config:

```
 <system.web>
   <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2" />
   <authentication mode="Windows"/>
   <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2"/>
 </system.web>
 <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehaviour" name="Order.IOrders">
        <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding"  contract="Order.IOrders" behaviorConfiguration="web">
        </endpoint>
      </service>
    </services>

    <behaviors>
       <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ServiceBehaviour">
        <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
        <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
        <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="web">
      <webHttp/>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<protocolMapping>
    <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https"  />
 </protocolMapping>    
 <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  <client>
  <endpoint
      name=""
      address="http://localhost:59837/Order.svc"
      binding="basicHttpBinding"
      contract="Order.IOrders" />
</client>
 </system.serviceModel>
 <system.webServer>
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  <!--
    To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
    Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
  -->
   <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
</system.webServer>
```

The code in the client app:

```
 ServiceReference1.OrdersClient client = new ServiceReference1.OrdersClient();          
        client.checkOrderNumber(txtNum.Text.ToString());
    }
```

Comment: Read [ask] and share your research. Your client config has an error, as the exception indicates.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description and code details, It seems that you want to invoke the WCF Service by adding service reference, you need to add **WebHttpBehavior** to the client endpoint.
You could refer to the following code.

```
    <system.serviceModel>
      <behaviors>
        <endpointBehaviors>
          <behavior name="webEndpoint">
            <webHttp defaultBodyStyle="Wrapped"
                     defaultOutgoingResponseFormat="Xml"
                     helpEnabled="true"/>
          </behavior>
        </endpointBehaviors>
      </behaviors>
      <client>
        <endpoint name="myclient" address="http://localhost:9001/Service1.svc" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="ServiceReference1.IService1" behaviorConfiguration="webEndpoint"></endpoint>
      </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.